# Kivy How to increase object with MySQL

Tags: python, kivy

On Kivy

Kivy How to increase object with MySQL

Example Code

```
import MySQLdb

connector = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", db="sdb", user="msusr", 
passwd="mspsw", charset="utf8")
cursor = connector.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from test_table order by code")

result = cursor.fetchall()

for row in result:

    #I don't know from here
    #How should i write code with class

cursor.close()
connector.close()
```

And kivy file is here

```
<WelcomeScreen>:

Button:
    text: ""
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Thankyou

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what "increas[ing] object" means. What do you want to achieve, and how does the current result differ from that? See [this help on good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Generally stackoverflow is not for "write this code for me" but rather "This specific code does X but it should do Y".

Comment: Please refer to the Kivy and SQLite3 example posted for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193573/how-to-access-kivy-textinput-text-attribute-from-py-file/46228743#46228743